# I get the error "The return value was unknown. The process exit code was 128.The Step failed" when executing a ssis package from an SQL job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, jobs

I am getting that error when executing an SSIS package (.dtsx) from a sql job.

The package has two connections, one with a local database and one against a remote database. The databases have the same structure, and basically what this package does is transfer records from the local database to the remote one.

The package is tested, in fact if it is run manually in visual studio it works correctly. The problem comes in execution from the SQL Job. In that case it is when you get the error message.

On the same computer I have other packages that do the same (they share the local database but they work with another remote database) and they work correctly and do not give this error.

Any idea what could be the problem that is causing this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to track down the real error message. Try using the package's logging function (right click on the background -> Logging), run the package again and check the error message. Most of these errors are either routes that are unavailable or users/logins without enough priviledges that changes whenever you run it from a different source (like Visual Studio vs. SQL Agent Job, for example).

Comment: Thanks, I will try to enable logging and launch the job again to see if I can get more error information.

Answer (score 0):

are you using SSIS Catalog?

were is the package located for the sql scheduler?

I had similar problem but when i moved the package to SSIS Catalog the problem was solved.

Kfir

Comment: The packages are located on a disk drive. All packages, those that work and the one that gives the error, are in that same disk drive.

Comment: Can you try, just for the test, to move the problematic package to SSIS Catalog?